# Estimate PDF from only positive data

Tags: r, density-function, kde

I have experemental data that not contain negative values (and theoretically can not contain negative values). When I do kernel density estimates of probability distribution function in `R` I get function which start from negative values. Something like that:

```
set.seed(12345)
data<-rlnorm(100,0,0.5)
plot(density(data, kernel="gaussian"))
```

I think if i take kernel like "lognormal" (which itself can not be negative), I get what I need. But such kernels no in `density` function. How to be with such data?

**added**

I use function from this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/how-can-i-estimate-the-density-of-a-zero-inflated-parameter-in-r) (I have no zeros in data):

```
set.seed(12345)
x<-rlnorm(100,0,0.5)
hist(x, freq=F, xlim=c(-0.3,4))
lines(density(x, kernel="gaussian"), col="blue")

logdensity <- function (x, bw = "SJ") 
{ 
  y <- log(x)
  g <- density(y, bw = bw, n = 1001)
  xgrid <- exp(g$x)
  g$y <- c(0, g$y/xgrid)
  g$x <- c(0, xgrid)
  return(g)
}

fit <- logdensity(x)
lines(fit$x,fit$y, col="red")
```

left tail `density` function  (blue line) starts from negative, left tail of new function (red line) start later then zero (with lag). But I ned start KDE line directly after zero, this agrees with nature of the data.

Comment: It took me a while to find that one (I knew I had seen it somewhere - it is missing a crucial tag though!) I'm thinking that will solve your problem, but if not just clarify how this is a different situation.

Comment: That approach @AndyW points to (which is what I usually do in similar situations) effectively does more smoothing in the tail where you need it and guarantees the smooth estimate is on the correct domain.