# KDE for censored data

Tags: kernel-smoothing, censoring, density-estimation

I have a sample of observations where about $30\%$ of the observations are right-censored. I want to fit a kernel density estimator to this sample but I have not found a standard method to do so. Is there any widely accepted methodology for fitting a KDE in the presence of censored observations?

Comment: Hmm, it is similar, but not quite the same situation as in [zero-inflated data](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6596/1036). In spatial statistics with *truncated* data you can weight points closer to the boundary, but that logic is not easily translated to censored data off-hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. In order to do anything with censored data you need to assume at least 'censoring at random', which says that the hazard for observations censored at time $t$ is the same conditional on  covariates as  for uncensored observations  still alive  at time $t$.

The main difference from ordinary uncensored KDE is that the effective sample size decreases  as more observations are censored, so that a constant bandwidth is unlikely to be optimal.

One of the earliest references  (now open access) is [a 1983 paper by Tanner & Wong](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176346265). There are implementations such as https://rdrr.io/cran/kernhaz/man/khazard.html and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/muhaz/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Kernel density estimates probability density function of the *empirical* distribution, it doesn't "know" and "care" about the underlying distribution. By "empirical" we mean here that it uses only the observed data and makes minimal distributional assumptions. Obviously, if it uses the observed data, it cannot say anything about the censored, unobserved data. If you say that the distribution is censored, it means that you should have some notion of the underlying distribution, so you should use it to define a parametric model to estimate the density.

Comment: You lost me at estimating the empirical distribution. We have the empirical distribution; what is there to estimate?

Comment: @Dave improved the wording.